# How to supply sudo with password from script?

Tags: linux, bash, file-permissions, sudo

**Please note:** this is a guest VM (VBox) running on my local machine, and I'm not worried about security.

I am writing a script that will be executed on a Linux (Ubuntu) VM as the `myuser` user. This script will create a very large directory tree under `/etc/myapp`. Currently I have to do all this manually, and it starts with me giving `myuser` recrusive *rwx* permissions under `/etc` like so:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /etc
[sudo] password for myuser:  <now I enter the password and hit ENTER>
```

My question: how do I write a bash script that supplies the `sudo` command with my password so that I can just execute `bash myscript.sh` and it will make the necessary permission changes for me?

Comment: (If you're remotely security conscious): You don't embed the password in the script; instead, you configure sudo not to ask for a password at all (when running that command, as that user). See `man sudoers` for documentation.

Comment: ...but then, if you're remotely security conscious, you don't **EVER** `chmod 777` the whole of /etc, either. Keep in mind that `o+rwx` doesn't just mean users you've intentionally given access to the machine -- it also means untrusted processes (including ones handling inbound unauthenticated network connections) running as the `nobody` account get permission to modify absolutely everything on your system, passwords included.

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy (+1) - I should have mentioned, this is a VBox VM running locally on my machine, and not running anything important/secure. So **no** (!) I'm not even *remotely* security conscious here!

Comment: If you want to let everyone do everything with no password by asking sudo, perhaps that should be your question.

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy (+1) however I'm not following you here... can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If, as you say, you *completely* don't care about security...

Run `visudo` to edit `/etc/sudoers` with validation in place. Add the following line:

```
ALL ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

This will prevent `sudo` from ever asking for a password, for any user, for any command.

Comment: Thanks @Charles Duffy (+1) - however wouldn't `sudo chmod -R 777 /etc | mypassword` also work?

Comment: @IAmYourFaja, why/how would you expect piping output from sudo (which has no output) into a program called "mypassword" to do anything useful?

Comment: @IAmYourFaja, ...now, if you're asking why `echo mypasswd | sudo ...` doesn't work, that's because sudo doesn't read passwords from stdin for security reasons; rather, it reads them from the TTY.

Comment: Thanks again @Charles Duffy (+1) - however when I run `visudo` from the command line, it says `Permission denied`. To run it, I need to execute `sudo visudo` and then supply my password. **This defeats the purpose of what I'm trying to do.** I need to be able to give myself permissions on this VM without having to use `sudo`! Ideas?

Comment: @IAmYourFaja, `visudo` is a thing you run *once*, *by hand*, to configure permissions which will stick thereafter. It's not a tool for programmatic use.

Comment: Does using this open my machine up to easier entry remotely? I'm not worried about locally - Locally have sole control and use over/of this system.

Comment: @ShefSam, the problem is that unprivileged users like `nobody` are used to sandbox code that's authenticating remote connection attempts. You can't safely assume that every user account reflects a real local user -- some of them are used by daemons that handle remote connections, so allowing local privilege escalation attacks makes bugs in daemons' authentication surfaces more serious.

Comment: @ShefSam, ...so if you completely trust human users but want to be secure against remote intrusion, instead of opening this up to `ALL` you should open it up to a group that only accounts tied to human users (not to daemons) are in.

Answer (score 6):

(BASH)
OK, if you've gotta do it, (keeping security warnings in mind):

> $ sudo -S < <(echo "<your password>") <your sudo command>

Comment: imho the only answer which actually answers the question. ty!!

Comment: `$ sudo -S < <(echo "<your password>") bash` does not work

Answer (score 0):

You can use `expect` or `autoexpect`. It's a bad idea, though.

Never put system passwords into writing. At least, not on a file on said system. Much less on an install script known to require root access. You're making yourself an easy target.

What you do instead, is configure `sudo` via `/etc/sudoers/` to allow **exactly that user** to execute **exactly that script** without a password:

```
myuser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD : /path/to/script
```

Note:

- If you remove the `/path/to/script` part, `myuser` will be able to `sudo` anything with no password.
- If you change `myuser` for `ALL`, everyone will be able to run that script with no password.

Comment: Thanks! However wouldn't `sudo chmod -R 777 /etc | mypassword` also just work?

Comment: @IAmYourFaja, first, because the syntax is wrong. Second, because sudo reads passwords from the TTY, not from stdin.

Comment: @IAmYourFaja, ...that's why the answer here is suggesting `expect`, which simulates a TTY, if you really want to do it in the way that advertises your password to the world (as opposed to the sane situation, in which case only a salted hash of your password can be recovered even after a system has been broken into).

Comment: Thanks again, however please see my comment under Charles Duffy's answer. I don't want to use `sudo` at all during this setup. Does `expect` or `autoexpect` help here? If so, can you give an example (I'm not familiar with `expect`)? Thanks again so much!

Comment: @IAmYourFaja, ...yes, expect would help, but it's damn foolish. How are you getting into this situation to start with? If you have a VM with a guest OS install, why can't you install a RSA public key with root permissions into ~root/.ssh/authorized_keys at the same time and use that for privilege escalation?

Comment: @IAmYourFaja, ...part of the point of learning to do things right is having good practices in your head so you can use them in situations when security *does* matter. If you don't learn skills until you need them, you're making trouble for yourself later.